# JavaScript Function with multi-parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to send this with eval as paramters for javascript function ?

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="rd" ClientIDMode="AutoID" onclick='<%# String.Format("OnCheckChange(\"{0}\", \"{1}\");", this, Eval("BookID"))%>' />
```

this way doesn't work  and here my function which always return

> Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

```
 function OnCheckChange(rb,idm ) {

        //logic for exclusive setting the radio button that was last clicked.
        var table = document.getElementById('ListTable');

        var radiobtn = table.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (k = 0; k < radiobtn.length; k++)
        {
            if ((radiobtn[k].type == 'radio') && (rb.id == radiobtn[k].id))
            {
                radiobtn[k].checked = true;
        }
            else
                radiobtn[k].checked = false;

        }

        //Book id against the selected radio button.
      var hdfield = rb.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input');

      if (hdfield[0].type == 'hidden')
          document.getElementById("hdnField").value = idm;

        //enabling /disabling buttons on the basis of checkin /checkout

      if (rb.parentNode.parentNode.cells[6].innerHTML == 'Checked In') {
          document.getElementById('btnCheckIn').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('btnCheckOut').disabled = true;
      }
      else if (rb.parentNode.parentNode.cells[6].innerHTML == 'Checked Out') {
          document.getElementById('btnCheckOut').disabled = true;
          document.getElementById('btnCheckIn').disabled = false;
      }

    }
```

if i send this without eval its work

Comment: `rb` is a string is not an object

Comment: `\"{0}\"` I think this is making the first argument into a string. try just `{0}` without the quote marks